# Реализация многопоточности в pygame

Tags: python, многопоточность, pygame

Пишу простенькую игру с видом сверху на pygame. Есть несколько модулей всё такое. При нажатии лкм персонаж начинает двигаться в точку куда была нажата лкм. Но есть одна проблема, догадаться о способе решения которой мне пока не удалось: как заставить персонажа поменять маршрут прямо во время движения при нажатии лкм?

```
while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                pygame.quit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:

                Mouse_Position = X_Click_Pos, Y_Click_Pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                print(Mouse_Position)

                for Subject in Subjects.All_Subjects['TactileObjects']:

                    if not ((Subject.X_Cord + Subject.Hit_Box_Width > X_Click_Pos > Subject.X_Cord) and
                       (Subject.Y_Cord + Subject.Hit_Box_Height > Y_Click_Pos > Subject.Y_Cord)):

                        Warrior_one.directional_movement(X_Click_Pos, Y_Click_Pos)
```

Comment: Вам нужен таймер. Интервал его выполнения - это скорость перемещения вашего перса. При каждом выполнении таймера нужно говорить персу сделать один шаг по направлению к выбранной координате. Когда вы жмете лкм, вы должны устанавливать переменную координаты - следующий шаг будет сделан уже с ее учетом.

Comment: Вам остается только найти, как создавать таймер в python

Comment: Идея крутая,  но есть одна проблема  в реализации, ведь я пробывал сделать нечто такое, но когда я нажимаю лкм во время движения. игра считывает ивент, но координаты точки берет, только после выполнения движения. Из-за этого кста есть еще один баг, что персонаж после изначального передвижения пойдет не туда куда я нажал. а туда, где была мышька по окончанию его движения

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

```
def add_Notify():
    if trhead == 0:
        pygame.threads.__nonzero__()
        pygame.threads.start()
           
    
def run_loop():
    running =True
    while running:
        add_Notify()
        for i in pygame.event.get():
            if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        clock.tick(FPS) 
        pygame.display.update()   
            
run_loop()
```

Осталось вставить в этот код ваш.